# String stored in memory as bits

Tags: java, memory, bit

I am learning about bits and how memory stores integers and other datatypes. I know that `int a = 11` will be stored in memory as bits as `1011`. How will `String b = "11"` be stored as bits.

Comment: must know borders between 'digits', in hypothetical stream decimal will be stored as (mark)1011. Without cannot intepret correct bits. Suggest amateur contact with compression algorithms, very interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, an int on most machines is stored as

00000000000000000000000000001011

It will always use the word size on the language/machine (or 32 bits in most cases).

A string is an object. it has a variety of properties and the implementation can vary a lot between languages. For the main portion, the actual string data, there are two fairly typical ways of storing it:  storing length separately, or null termination.

Either way it determines the length, the characters are stored as a sequence of bytes. The size of each character depends on language/compiler settings, etc. In order to support non-english languages and special characters, it is common to store 16bits per character, but older languages often still use 8.

character encoding is based off the old ASCII table, but newer specifications cover a lot more. Check out UTF-8 and UTF-16.

But, for just understanding the basics, the ASCII table gives us somewhere to go. Each character in the string is defined by a number, and then that number is encoded in binary, just like an int.

http://www.asciitable.com/

The character "1" is represented by the ASCII code 49 (decimal), which in binary is 00110001.  The entire string may look like:

001100010011000100000000

including a null terminator.

Comment: the final 8 0's would be the null terminator, which indicates the end of the string. Not always used.

Comment: I ask this because those are 24 bits. Would it just put bunch of zeroes on the left side?

Comment: there would be an extra 8 bits, yes. I consider byte-ordering beyond the scope, but Intel does it differently than most.

Comment: good answer in context "store in constant word machines". But answer has nothing to possible question "what is highest possible storing algorithm" (more or less professional compression)

Comment: the question was "in memory" not what is sometimes used for transmission or file system storage. Examples of huffman encoding being used to save RAM are scarce.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(final byte b : "11".getBytes()) {
        String asBinary = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
        System.out.print(asBinary);
    }
}
```

Comment: So `b & 0xFF` is a bit-masking operation, Integer.toBinaryString converts a value to it's binary representation (e.g. 110001), String.format is print padding it out to 8 places (byte width) and the replace at the end zero pads (instead of space pads).